# Aurelia: How to add and remove custom attributes from view-model

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

How do I add and remove custom attributes from a view-model?

Adding the attribute with targetElement.SetAttribute('mycustomelement') won't activate the Aurelia custom attribute.

Could TemplatingEngine.Enhance() bring life to the custom-attribute from the view-model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div id="dummy">lorum ipsum</div>
<button click.delegate="addAttribute()">click here</button>
```

with code behind

```
public addAttribute() {

    let el = document.getElementById("dummy");
    el.setAttribute("css.bind", "{ color: 'red' }");

    if (el && !el.querySelectorAll('.au-target').length) {
      var element = this.templatingEngine.enhance(el);
      console.dir( element.viewFactory );
    }
}
```

Don't know how to unbind this and it will (I guess) give either memory problems or errors when you attach an element multiple times (so added a check for .au-target). The documentation above the function says you are now responsible for the life cycle of it.

What is it that you try to accomplish? There might be a better way..

Comment: Almost, I'm trying to activate a custom-attribute and the enhance-method won't invoke any life-cycle methods of the attribute.

It seems like this only adds the attribute to the DOM but doesn't go through the aurelia-templating-bits.

Comment: Hmm, it's not my first choice, but you could include "aurelia-testing" and let it render the full html for you and then replace it, but then it would not update anymore on changes I guess, but will run through bind/attach/etc. Feels like a nasty hack :-) Or check the code of aurelia-testing to see if you can find something from there to get it working :-)

Comment: Good tips, I went through the src for aurelia-testing and they really wrap the life-cycle up and injects the attribute-resources. Way too complex for a "simple thing" as adding an attribute and I can agree that it feels a little bit hacky. :-)